# ServiceStack new api routing under MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I have an MVC project with ServiceStack mounted at /api. Request DTOs are decorated with the Route attribute. In AppHost config, i've set ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api".

My assumption was that the route on the DTOs would not require the path prefix, i.e. i could use [Route("thing/{id}/blah")] as opposed to [Route("api/thing/{id}/blah")], though i can only get the latter to work.

Is this as intended or an oversight ?

Comment: try `ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "/api"`